# Neon casting issue

Tags: arm, simd, neon, int32, uint8t

I am new to the NEON intrinsics (A9 processor).

I want to convert `uint8x16_t` to `int32x4_t` value .
I tried to use the `vreinterpret_s32_u8` to do so which did not work .

Can anyone please guide me? Really appreciate your help .

Answer (score 2):

8x16 = 128, you need to operate on quad word vectors.

> vreinterpret{q}_dsttype_srctype
>
> Where:
>
> q
>
> Specifies that the conversion operates on 128-bit vectors. If it is not present, the conversion operates on 64-bit vectors.

Which should be

> int32x4_t vreinterpret**q**_s32_u8 (uint8x16_t __a)

Comment: sorry my mistake ..i interpret this api as vreinterpret128_s32_u8 instaed of  vreinterpretq_s32_u8 .But I simply thought to use vreinterpret .Is it correct as my solution ??

Comment: @user3476225 This is just a compiler level type safety construct, it shouldn't do any actual instruction level casting. So if it compiles, high chance it will work. Checking disassembly is also a good exercise to see the instruction layout.